# Jinja2 - add class using range inside for loop

Tags: python, jinja2

This prints as many stars that's passed in `review.rating`

```
<div class="ratings">
  {% for review reviews') %}
    {% for n in range(review.rating) %}
      <span class="review-star review-star-active">★</span>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The output that I can get with the above code is:

```
<div class="ratings">
  <span class="review-star review-star-active">★</span>
  <span class="review-star review-star-active">★</span>
  <span class="review-star review-star-active">★</span>
</div>
```

But the output I needed is:

```
<div class="ratings">
  <span class="review-star review-star-active">★</span>
  <span class="review-star review-star-active">★</span>
  <span class="review-star review-star-active">★</span>
  <span class="review-star">★</span>
  <span class="review-star">★</span>
</div>
```

I am not sure how can I do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always loop five times, but compare the current counter with the rating and output the active class if it is less or equal.

```
{% for n in range(5) %}
  <span class="review-star {% if n <= review.rating %}review-star-active{% endif %}">★</span>
{% endfor %}
```